# Is "Arithmetic Expansion" the expected action on vars inside `[[` tests?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh, ksh

This script:

```sh
a=2
[[ "$a" -eq 2 ]] && echo yes1
[[  $a  -eq 2 ]] && echo yes2
[[   a  -eq 2 ]] && echo yes3
[[  "a" -eq 2 ]] && echo yes4
```

Does not work in [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) (and some others that do not have [[ ).
Fails the last two "yes tests" in [ash](/questions/tagged/ash) (BusyBox ash). As I expected.

But, quite UN expectly:
This happens when the arithmetic  » -eq «  is being used (and some other).
Prints all the four yes in [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh), [ksh93](/questions/tagged/ksh93), [lksh](/questions/tagged/lksh), [mksh](/questions/tagged/mksh), [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh).

## Q's

Is this the natural side effect of "Arithmetic Expansion" being applied to labels like (`a`) ?.
(nothing to see, move along ?)

Should (`a`) still be expanded as a variable when quoted: `"a"`?

Is this documented somewhere I haven't look into yet?

Or, Is a simple (very old) bug?

## Edit

#### To really get you thinking, check this:

```sh
a=2; b=2

[[ "$a" -eq "$b"                 ]] && echo yes1
[[  $a  -eq "$b"                 ]] && echo yes2
[[   a  -eq "$b"                 ]] && echo yes3
[[  "a" -eq "$b"                 ]] && echo yes4
[[ "$a" -eq "$b" && "$a" == "$b" ]] && echo new1
[[  $a  -eq "$b" &&  $a  == "$b" ]] && echo new2
[[   a  -eq "$b" &&   a  == "$b" ]] && echo new3
[[  "a" -eq "$b" &&  "a" == "$b" ]] && echo new4
```

All yes work, only new1 and new2 do. The var a is not being expanded in new3 & 4.

That means that shells switch mode (Arithmetic -- String) in the middle of the evaluation.

This doesn't seem so obvious to me. At least, is not simple, IMO.

Note that ash does it in a different way. And also report the error.

## Conclusion:

I do not know the correct answer. But I suspect (looking at so many shells doing it exactly the same way) that it is a very well known way (to developers) in which this tests should work. It should be up to us to understand the fact and adapt.

Seems that for numeric `-eq` the only possible 'Conditional Expression' to apply is:

```sh
exp1 -eq exp2
          true if exp1 is numerically equal to exp2.
```

Which makes both sides of the `-eq` "Arithmetic expressions"

While for the `==` the only possible 'Conditional Expression' to apply is:

```sh
string == pattern
          true if string matches pattern. ....
```

Which makes the left hand side an string (no expansion?) and the right hand side a pattern (which really do not apply to the test I presented as all were quoted on the right side to avoid this complexity. So, right hand side defaults (being quoted) to an string also (no arithmetic expansion here).

But maybe I am more confused than I though :-)

What do you say?

Answer (score 6):

From `man ksh`:

> An arithmetic expression uses the same syntax, precedence, and associativity of expression as the C language. All the C language operators that apply to floating point quantities can be used... Variables can be referenced by name within an arithmetic expression without using the parameter expansion syntax. When a variable is referenced, its value is evaluated as an arithmetic expression...
>
> A conditional expression is used with the `[[` compound command to test attributes of *files* and to compare *strings*. Field splitting and file name generation are not performed on the words between `[[` and `]]`. Each expression can be constructed from one or more of the following unary or binary expressions...
>
> The following obsolete arithmetic comparisons are also permitted:
>
> - *`exp1`*`-eq`*`exp2`*
>
>   - True, if *`exp1`* is equal to *`exp2`*.
> - *`exp1`*`-ne`*`exp2`*
>
>   - True, if *`exp1`* is not equal to *`exp2`*.
> - *`exp1`*`-lt`*`exp2`*
>
>   - True, if *`exp1`* is less than *`exp2`*.
> - *`exp1`*`-gt`*`exp2`*
>
>   - True, if *`exp1`* is greater than *`exp2`*.
> - *`exp1`*`-le`*`exp2`*
>
>   - True, if *`exp1`* is less than or equal to *`exp2`*.
> - *`exp1`*`-ge`*`exp2`*
>
>   - True, if *`exp1`* is greater than or equal to *`exp2`*.

---

The documentation there is consistent where references to arithmetic *expressions* are concerned, and *(apparently carefully)* avoids any self-contradictions surrounding the definition of the `[[` *compound command* `]]` pertaining to *string comparison* by explicitly *also permitting* some *obsolete arithmetic comparisons* in the same context.

---

From `man bash`:

> `[[`*`expression`*`]]`
>
> - Return a status of `0` or `1` depending on the evaluation of the condi‐ tional expression *`expression`*. Expressions are composed of the primaries described below... Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between the `[[` and `]]`; `~`tilde expansion, `${`parameter`}` and `$`variable expansion, `$((`arithmetic expansion`))`, `$(`command substitution`)`, `<(`process substitution`)`, and `"\'`quote removal are performed. Conditional operators such as `-f` must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries...
>
> A *variable* may be assigned to by a statement of the form:
>
> - *`name`*`=`*`[value]`*
>
> If *`value`* is not given, the variable is assigned the null string. All values undergo `~`tilde expansion, `${`parameter`}` and `$`variable expansion, `$(`command substitution`)`, `$((`arithmetic expansion`))`, and `"\'`quote removal... If the *variable* has its *integer attribute* set, then *`value`* is evaluated as an `$((`arithmetic expression`))` even if the `$((`*`...`*`))` expansion is not used...
>
> The shell allows arithmetic *`expressions`* to be evaluated, under certain circumstances... Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error. The operators and their precedence, associativity, and values are the same as in the C language.
>
> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an *`expression`*, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax. The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic *`expression`* when it is referenced, or when a variable which has been given the integer attribute using `declare -i` is assigned a value... A shell variable need not have its integer attribute turned on to be used in an expression.
>
> Conditional *`expressions`* are used by the `[[` *compound command* and the `test` and `[` *builtin commands* to test file attributes and perform string and arithmetic comparisons...
>
> `arg1`*`OP`*`arg2`
>
> - *`OP`* is one of `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`. These arithmetic binary operators return true if *`arg1`* is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to *`arg2`*, respectively. *`arg1`* and *`arg2`* may be positive or negative integers.

---

I think, given all that context, the behavior you observe stands to reason, even if it is not explicitly spelled out as a possibility in the documentation there. The docs do point to special treatment of *parameters* with *integer attributes*, and clearly denote a difference between a *compound command* and a *builtin command*.

The `[[` comparison is *syntax* in the same sense that the assignment *`name`*`=`*`value`* is *syntax* or `case`*`word`*`in...` is *syntax*. `test` and `[`, however, are not as such, and are rather separate procedures which take arguments. As I think, the best way to really get a feel for the differences is to have a look at shell error output:

```sh
set   '[[ \\ -eq 0 ]]' '[ \\ -eq 0 ]'
for    sh in   bash ksh
do     for     exp
       do     "$sh" -c  "$1||$2"
               set "$2" "$1"
done;  done
```

---

```
bash: [[: \: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\")
bash: line 0: [: \: integer expression expected
bash: line 0: [: \: integer expression expected
bash: [[: \: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\")
ksh: \: arithmetic syntax error
ksh: [: \: arithmetic syntax error
ksh: \: arithmetic syntax error
```

The two shells handle the exceptions differently, but the underlying reasons for the differences in both cases for both shells are very similar.

- `bash` directly calls the `[[ \\` case a *syntax error* - in the same way it might for a redirect from a non-existent file, for example - though it goes on from that point *(as I believe, incorrectly)* to evaluate the other side of the `||` or expression. `bash` *does* give the `[[` expression a *command name* in error output, but note that it doesn't bother discussing the line number on which you call it as it does for the `[` command. `bash`'s `[` complains about not receiving what it expects to be an *integer expression* as an argument, but `[[` need not complain in that way because it doesn't really take arguments, and never needs to *expect* anything at all when it is parsed alongside the expansions themselves.
- `ksh` halts altogether when the `[[` syntax error and doesn't bother with `[` at all. It writes the same error message for both, but note that `[` is assigned a *command name* there where `[[` is just *`ksh`*. The `[` is only called after the command-line has been successfully parsed and expansions have already occurred - it will do its own little `getopts` routine and get its own `arg[0c]` and the rest, but `[[` is handled as underlying shell syntax once again.

I consider the `bash` docs slightly less clear than the `ksh` version in that they use the terms *`arg[12]`* rather than *`expression`* regarding integer comparisons, but I think it is done merely because `[[`, `[`, and `test` are all lumped together at that juncture, and the latter two do take *arguments* whereas the former only ever receives an *`expression`*.

In any case, where the integer comparison is not ambiguous in the *syntax* context, you can basically do any valid math operation mid-*`expression`*:

```sh
   m=5+5  a[m]=10
[[     m   -eq 10 ]] &&
[[     m++ -eq 10 ]] &&
[[     m-- -gt 10 ]] &&
[[ ${a[m]}  == 10 ]] &&
echo "math evals"
```

---

```
math evals
```

Comment: Excellent description. Thanks for your time and effort !

Comment: This (from ksh manual): `Variables can be referenced by name within an arithmetic expression without using the parameter expansion syntax.` exactly explains the reason for expansion of a simple character: ` a ` (inside an Arithmetic Expression). It seems to also apply to "Arithmetic Comparison" inside `[[` brackets. That clears up that point. Thanks.

Comment: The arithmetic expansion being performed inside `[[` seems to apply to the use of this form of test: `[[ $(( 3-2 )) -eq 1 ]]`. That is: arithmetic `$((...))` constructs are allowed **and** evaluated inside `[[`. That's all. It does not (IMhO) seem to apply to the expansion of a simple character `a`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - yes. in fact, whenever possible, you should drop `$` in arithmetic expressions entirely. for example: `x=FS; printf '<%s>\n' $((I$x=0)) "$IFS"` prints `<>\n<0>\n`

Comment: @BinaryZebra - no. that's an arithmetic *expansion* - which substitutes out the ultimate value of one or more arithmetic *expressions* as an argument.

Comment: I completely agree with the whole paragraph: `I consider the bash docs slightly less clear than the ksh version` .

Comment: @BinaryZebra - well, to be fair, `bash` was never mass-marketed world-wide as the official UNIX shell by AT&T either. but `ksh` is *way* better. `bash` is, without a doubt, my very least favorite shell to use in every way/

Comment: The point to which you are answering "no. that's an arithmetic expansion" was made about the paragraph where it starts: `From man bash: [[expression]] Return a status of 0 or 1`. That paragraph does contain an `arithmetic expansion` reference. Again: This discussion should not be held in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31978/discussion-between-mikeserv-and-binaryzebra).

Comment: And my **last** comment here: You could also add `[[ m+=3,--m   -eq 12 ]] && echo "done"` to the last tests and see a `done` printed. It is a full "arithmetic evaluation" space.

Answer (score 3):

This is very well documented, e.g. in `bash`:

```
   [[ expression ]]
          [...] Word splitting and pathname expansion
          are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]];
          tilde expansion, parameter  and  variable  expansion,
          arithmetic  expansion, command substitution, process 
          substitution, and quote removal are performed.
```

or in `zsh`:

```
    CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
          A  conditional expression is used with the [[ compound
          command to test...
          [...]
          In  the  forms  which  do numeric comparison,
          the expressions exp undergo arithmetic
          expansion as if they were enclosed in $((...)).
```

Comment: While it's well-documented in zsh, the Bash documentation doesn't really say it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer `arithmetic  expansion ... are performed`. What more do you need?

Comment: Well, for a start, [arithmetic expansion is `$(( expression ))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), which isn't involved here. Secondly, `[[ a == 5 ]]` remains false (of course); it's only the arithmetic binary operators that do shell arithmetic, which isn't described in either the quote or the rest of the manual.

Comment: In fact the only thing it does seem to say about the arguments to numeric operators is is "*Arg1* and *arg2* may be positive or negative integers", which isn't very helpful in this circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

`[[` is not a POSIX feature but a `ksh88` feature.

If you like to know what happens you would need to read the ksh documentation.

As you seem to be interested to understand the `[[` feature, you need to know that `[[` is not a builtin command like `[` but part of the shell syntax, so it's work base differs completely from the `test` command.

For this reason, e.g. `[[ $var == *test? ]]` does not need to put the pattern on the right side into quotes.