# A Unix AIX variable without a $ symbol?

Tags: variable, ksh, aix, test, numeric-data

I'm trying to debug an existing program and found an if condition without $ symbol prefixed to it.

Values are:

```
dt_val=1234
prev_dt_val=1234
```

If condition goes like:

```
if [ dt_val -eq prev_dt_val ]
then
  echo "Equal"
else
  echo "Not equal"
fi

Result:
Equal
```

Anyone throw some light on how the condition is working fine without a $ symbol?  
Shouldn't that be..?

```
[ $dt_val -eq $prev_dt_val ]
```

The same condition fails when comparing string values.  Does that mean, this condition does not require a $ symbol for number?

Additional info:
Comparing Strings with == as suggested:

```
dt_val="abcd"
prev_dt_val="abcd"

if [ dt_val == prev_dt_val ]
> then
> echo Equal
> else
> echo Not equal
> fi
Not equal
```

Shell Info:

```
echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/ksh
Version M-11/16/88f
```

Wondering why there's no error either.

Comment: It might help illustrate the situation better if you demonstrate unequal values comparing (successfully) as unequal, without `$`

Comment: Really similar, but talks about `[[` instead of `[` -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244685/117549

Comment: If I was to guess, ksh is using the same code as [[ and is performing variable expansion "for" you.

Comment: Could you split the question into separate examples of string versus numeric values for testing? Using `-eq` would be wrong for strings (use `=` or `!=` for strings).

Comment: Updated the question with == comparison.

Comment: The `[` is a built-in command, and it may treat the `-eq` test as a proper arithmetic context.  `$` is not needed on variables in an arithmetic context.

Answer (score 5):

In `ksh`, the builtin `[` takes the operands of `-eq` as in an arithmetic context, just like Bash does for `[[` and `-eq`. And in an arithmetic context, variables don't need the `$` sign.

```
$ ksh -c 'a=1 b=1; if [ a -eq b ]; then echo equal; else echo different; fi'
equal
$ ksh -c 'a=1 b=2; if [ a -eq b ]; then echo equal; else echo different; fi'
different
```

or even:

```
$ ksh -c 'a=2 b=8; if [ a*4 -eq b ]; then echo equal; else echo different; fi'
equal
$ ksh -c 'a=2 b=9; if [ a*4 -eq b ]; then echo equal; else echo different; fi'
different
```

(However, the `*` still globs, so `a*4` should be quoted there.)

That's ksh93, `ksh --version` shows `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`, it's from Debian's package (`ksh`, package version `93u+20120801-3.1`). I get the same result with Debian's `mksh`, so I suppose ksh88 is close enough here.

---

For comparison, in Bash that gives an error:

```
$ bash -c 'a=1 b=1; if [ a -eq b ]; then echo equal; else echo different; fi'
bash: line 0: [: a: integer expression expected
different
```

(it prints `different`, since `[` returns a falsy value on error).

With `[[` it works:

```
$ bash -c 'a=1 b=1; if [[ a -eq b ]]; then echo equal; else echo different; fi'
equal
```

Zsh is like Bash here, `[` errors on `a -eq b`, `[[` works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the script is not evaluatling the variables as it's missing the `$` in front of the variable names, like you also discovered.

Secondly, it's outputting "Equal" because it's using the numeric compare operator `-eq` in the `test` (`[`) command. As it's passed two non-numerical strings as parameters, they both evaluate to the same numeric value and hence the "Equal" string is output.

Note that at least by bash version complains:

```
$ if [ 0 -eq bla ]; then echo yes; fi
-bash: [: bla: integer expression expected
```

My dash version also complains:

```
$ if [ 0 -eq bla ]; then echo yes; fi
dash: 1: [: Illegal number: bla
```

I'm interested what shell you are using that doesn't complain.

Even if there are variables present with the names of those strings I get the same result.

Comment: but if you set `dt_val=5`, the test fails...

Comment: I'm using ksh.  It gives me the error when i'm comparing string values such as "abcd" **ksh: abcd: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command**

Comment: @JeffSchaller, No, it's not failing for me.  I get the result as **Equal**

Comment: dt_val=5
prev_dt_val=6
if [ dt_val -eq prev_dt_val ]
 then
 echo equal
 else
 echo not equal
 fi
not equal

Comment: @SanthoshRam what version of ksh?

Comment: It's **Version M-11/18/88f**, I believe.

Comment: Are you sure the script is also being executed by ksh?

Comment: Updated the question with Shell info.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Not just the script.  Even when i pass these on command line, it gives me the same result. :(